# Any event raised after an async function does not update UI properly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, xamarin.android

I am trying to add a basic callback to my app whereby a loading state label updates as the app progresses through an update task. For some reason though, after calling one particular async method, any events raised thereafter are not updating the UI.

I've tried various configure await settings and looked through the async method itself but I can't find anything obviously wrong.

```
public async Task RefreshTable<T>() where T : class, IEntity
    {
        try
        {
            OnContentUpdateProgressChange(this, new MessageEventArgs($"RefreshTable before {typeof(T).Name}"));
            var tableJsonData = await ApiService.GetEntityListAsync<T>();
            OnContentUpdateProgressChange(this, new MessageEventArgs($"RefreshTable after {typeof(T).Name}"));
            await LoadTableData(Set<T>(), tableJsonData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

public async Task<List<T>> GetEntityListAsync<T>(string url = null) where T : class
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            url = typeof(T).Name.Replace("_", "");
        }
        try
        {
            string entityList = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                entityList = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var backupFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), typeof(T).Name);
                using (var writer = File.CreateText(backupFile))
                {
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(entityList.ToString());
                }
            }
            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(entityList));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }


    private void DB_OnContentUpdateProgressChange(object sender, library.EventArguments.MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        lblLoadingState.Text = e.Message;
    }
```

The event raised before the call to GetEntityListAsync successfully updates the UI, the one after however doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

from what I read my understanding tells me this is a UI thread issue When you make some changes in a Background thread in your case the async method it is always recommended that the changes that you have made which will affect the UI should be done on the `MainThread` or the `UIThread`. Now what you need to do is quite simple. Whenever you make a change that is supposed to affect the UI in any kind do it on the UI thread.

What I like to do is make all the UI changes in a method then I like to have a base version of my Activity class that has helpers that let me check if it is the MainThread or not and make the changes accordingly use that method.

- Add an Activity that inherits from AppCompatActivity and then add the following to it.

  ```
   public abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
   {
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }

      public bool IsMainThread => Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M
      ? Looper.MainLooper.IsCurrentThread
      : Looper.MyLooper() == Looper.MainLooper;

      public void RunOnMainThread(Action action)
      {
        if (IsMainThread) action();
        else RunOnUiThread(action);
      } 

  }
  ```
- Then make UI changes like:

  ```
  RunOnMainThread(() => { LabelDoSomething.Text = "New Text"; });
  ```